# How to define range using sheet name from a cell value?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm fetching values and presenting them in a separate sheet.
How do i write the VLOOKUP so that it uses the value from column A?

[image]

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Use `INDIRECT`.

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add input table and expected output table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.